# How to use DNS resolver in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, mx-record

I want to check MX-Record from Python. So I installed the `dnspython` package, but when I try to import following library:

```
import dns.resolver
```

It shows the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'.
```

I use PyCharm and Python 3.

Comment: How did you install dns package? pip? If so please add `pip list` output as well

Comment: I install using pycharm..
ctrl+alt+S and click + sign there in python interpretor and search dnspython and install package

Comment: Can you try `import resolver from dns` and paste the error? Just to make sure the package is installed, look in the project interpreter and see that the package is listed.

Comment: import resolver from dns gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax   and  
from dns import resolver gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'

Comment: In the project Interpreter can you see the package? Clearly it is installing somewhere outside your project scope. Mostly in a different virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help..I got my answer
In python3 package is dnspython3 not dnspython

Answer (score 5):

You should install https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython first

> pip install dnspython

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was to add `dnspython` into the requirements file.

So in the `requirements.pinned.txt`:

```
...
dnspython==2.0.0
...
```

And in the `requirements.txt`:

```
dnspython
...
```